# Nativescript Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to upload a multipart form in nativescript and I'm using http-background. I keep getting the error Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'. I've tried changing the compilerOptions target to es5 and es2017, but nothing changed.

[image: Here's the entire error I'm seeing]

Here's all my code from the component.

```
  onSave(){
    console.log("clicked")
    this.proccessImageUpload(this.file);
  }



public onSelectSingleTap() {
  this.isSingleMode = true;

  let context = imagepicker.create({
      mode: "single"
  });
  this.startSelection(context);
}

private startSelection(context) {
  let that = this;

  context
  .authorize()
  .then(() => {
      that.imageAssets = [];
      that.imageSrc = null;
      return context.present();
  })
  .then((selection) => {
     console.log("Selection done: " + JSON.stringify(selection));
     this.file = selection[0]._android;    
    
     
    
      that.imageSrc = that.isSingleMode && selection.length > 0 ? selection[0] : null;

      // set the images to be loaded from the assets with optimal sizes (optimize memory usage)
      selection.forEach(function (element) {
          element.options.width = that.isSingleMode ? that.previewSize : that.thumbSize;
          element.options.height = that.isSingleMode ? that.previewSize : that.thumbSize;
      });

      that.imageAssets = selection;
  }).catch(function (e) {
      console.log(e);
  });
}

  // proccess image function
proccessImageUpload(fileUri) {
  var backgroundHttp  = require("nativescript-background-http");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // body...
      var request = {
          url: 'http://192.168.0.2:4000/api/posts',
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
              "user_id": "<user_id>"
          },
          description: 'Uploading profile image..',
          androidAutoDeleteAfterUpload: false,
          androidNotificationTitle: 'Profile image'
      }

      var params = [
        { name: "title", value: "test" },
        { name: "content", value: "test" },
        { name: "fileToUpload", filename: fileUri, mimeType: "image/jpeg" }
     ];

     var backgroundSession = backgroundHttp.session('image-upload');
     var task = backgroundSession.uploadFile(fileUri, request);

      task.on("progress", (e) => {
          // console log data
          console.log(`uploading... ${e.currentBytes} / ${e.totalBytes}`);
      });

      task.on("error", (e) => {
          // console log data
          console.log(`Error processing upload ${e.responseCode} code.`);
          reject(`Error uploading image!`);
      });

      task.on("responded", (e) => {
          // console log data
          console.log(`received ${e.responseCode} code. Server sent: ${e.data}`);
          // var uploaded_response = JSON.parse(e.data);
      });

      task.on("complete", (e) => {
          // console log data
          console.log(`upload complete!`);
          console.log(`received ${e.responseCode} code`);
          // console.log(e.data);
      })

      resolve(task);
  });
}
```

I know the issue is coming from this line.

```
var task = backgroundSession.uploadFile(fileUri, request);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You use old version if *nativescript-background-http* plugin

You have to install latest version

```
tns plugin add @nativescript/background-http
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by installing tns version 6.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I got this from slack.com, compliments Chris Vietor
"tns plugin add nativescript-background-http" works with nativescript 6.
"tns plugin add @nativescript/background-http" works with nativescript 7.